# Adding rows to the MVCContrib Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I'm developing my first MVC website and I'm experimenting with the few available grids out there.  I really like the MVCContrib grid, but I need to implement a standard "Add new record" functionality, and I don't see a clear way to add a single record to the database and grid without having to reload the entire grid each time.

I know there is a jQuery grid plugin, and if there's no good way to do this with MVCContrib I'll go that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much looking around it would seem that my best solution is a framework like jQuery or ExtJS.  MVCContrib Grid isn't there yet, if it ever will be.

Comment: After even more work, ExtJS is now my favorite new toy!  Takes some getting used to in combination with ASP.NET MVC, but it's worth it!